# Where can I find a dataset with labelled articles by topic?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am looking for a dataset containing articles (with article-text, or alternatively I am fine with only URLs too) and the corresponding topic label (i.e. politics, art, gardening etc.)
Any idea?

Comment: academic papers?

Answer (score 1):

The [News category dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rmisra/news-category-dataset) seems to fit your description.

> This dataset contains around 200k news headlines from the year 2012 to
>   2018 obtained from HuffPost. The model trained on this dataset could
>   be used to identify tags for untracked news articles or to identify
>   the type of language used in different news articles. Each news headline has a corresponding category (politics, entertainment, travel, etc.)

Alternatively, you can use:

[Reuters Text Categorization Dataset](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/reuters21578/reuters21578.html):

> This dataset contains 21,578 Reuters documents that appeared on
>   Reuters newswire in 1987. The dataset is split into a training set of
>   13,625, and a testing set of 6,188. Each document is tagged according
>   to date, topic, place, people, organizations, companies, and etc.

[The 20 Newsgroups Dataset](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/):

> The 20 Newsgroups Dataset is a popular dataset for experimenting with
>   text applications of machine learning techniques, including text
>   classification. The dataset collates approximately 20,000 newsgroup
>   documents partitioned across 20 different newsgroups, each
>   corresponding to a different topic. The website offers three versions
>   of the dataset for slightly different purposes.

You can refer to this [link](https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/14-best-text-classification-datasets-for-machine-learning/) for more.